# R, shiny: reactive data.frame as a factor, set levels and order

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, reactive

In my shiny app, I have a data.frame that is reactive. The data.frame is then given to ggplot and the barchart is made. However, I would like to set the exact order of the bars in the barchart. 
This I can do with

```
    JOIN11$ID_Polymer <- factor(JOIN11$ID_Polymer, 
                            levels=JOIN11$ID_Polymer[order(JOIN11[["Content"]])])
```

in my R script (a `function()` that prepares the data outside the shiny server).

I would like to set the order in the shiny server so the user can change the ordering argument (the user can decide if he wants to order the data.frame by "Content" or by some other column that he chooses).
I was trying something like this:

```
dataforplot <- reactive({
  plot_data <-  data() %>% 
    filter(Name %in% input$polymers) 
   plot_data$ID_Polymer <- factor(plot_data$ID_Polymer, 
          levels =plot_data$ID_Polymer[ order(plot_data[["Content"]])])
})
```

which does not work (the `ggplot` is not displayed), the error says: `data must be a data frame, or other object coercible by`fortify()`, not a factor`.

the function for `ggplot` goes like this:

```
  plotInput <- reactive({



    ggplot(data = dataforplot(), aes(x = ID_Polymer, y = value), position = position_dodge(width = 1))  +
      geom_bar(aes_string( fill=razeni()), position = position_dodge(width = 1), stat="identity", color="white")+
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(legend.text=element_text(size=21))+
      theme(text = element_text(size=21))+
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
      ggtitle(input$title_text_box_id) + 
      labs(x = "", y = input$ylabel_text_box_id) + 
      geom_text(aes(x = ID_Polymer, y = value,Group=Polymer,label=value), 
                position = position_dodge(width = 1),vjust=2, size=5,colour = "white", fontface = "bold") +
      scale_fill_tableau("Tableau 10")+
     scale_x_discrete(labels=c(xpopisky()))#puts a reactive in x labels

  })
```

It works when I am not trying to set the order to the data.fram, when I leave out the

```
plot_data$ID_Polymer <- factor(plot_data$ID_Polymer, 
          levels =plot_data$ID_Polymer[ order(plot_data[["Content"]])])
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use:

```
dataforplot <- reactive({
  plot_data <-  data() %>% 
    filter(Name %in% input$polymers) 
   plot_data$ID_Polymer <- factor(plot_data$ID_Polymer, 
          levels =plot_data$ID_Polymer[ order(plot_data[["Content"]])])
})
```

The last line of whatever is inside your `reactive()` is returned as the value of that reactive element. Hence, in your case `plot_data$ID_Polymer`(which is not a dataframe, but a factor column of the dataframe) is returned as `dataforplot()`. This is the reason for the error. Change you `dataforplot()` definition to:

```
dataforplot <- reactive({
  plot_data <-  data() %>% 
    filter(Name %in% input$polymers) 
   plot_data$ID_Polymer <- factor(plot_data$ID_Polymer, 
          levels =plot_data$ID_Polymer[ order(plot_data[["Content"]])])
   # Add return statement for returning the dataframe
   return(plot_data)
})
```

Comment: It works perfectly, for my specific case it goes like this: 
dataforplot <- reactive({
  plot_data <-  data() %>% 
    filter(Name %in% input$polymers) 
    plot_data$ID_Polymer <- factor(plot_data$ID_Polymer, 
          levels =plot_data$ID_Polymer[ order(plot_data[[input$groupby]])])
    return(plot_data)
})
 Thanks a lot.